# Super call in custom exception

Tags: java, exception, constructor

I just want to know why we call super in own created custom exception.

```
public class MyException extends Exception 
{ 
   public MyException(String message)         
  {  
    super(message);        
  }      
}
```

Here What is the use of calling super(message)

Comment: It's to call the non-default super's constructor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since a derived class always has the base class as a template, it is necessary to initialize the base class as the first step in constructing the derived object. By default, if no `super` call is made, Java will use a default (parameterless) constructor to create the base class. If you want a different constructor to be used, you have to use `super` to pass in the parameters you want and invoke the correct constructor.

In the case of custom exceptions, it is common to use `super` to initialize the exception's error message; by passing the message into the base class constructor, the base class will take care of the work of setting the message up correctly.

Comment: if we are calling super constructor so what is the use of customized exception?

Comment: Hi @kavya. The use of the customized exception is in making any changes compared to the base exception. A simple use case would be modifying the message before passing to the `super()` call. However, you could also define any variables or methods on the derived class, which a consumer could use to get more information.

Comment: Can you explain why there is no constructor in the Exception that accepts an `int`? I have a custom exception class but I could not throw it from a `JNI` `C++` passing the `int` error code. But instead, I am compelled to instead use a `String` because the Exception class has a constructor that accepts a string.

Answer (score 2):

It's just calling the base class constructor:

> `Exception(String message)` 
>    Constructs a new exception with the specified detail message.

Answer (score 2):

Because:

```
public MyException(String message)         
  {  
   //super() implicit call, how to set message???

}
```

So you need a super(message) call to set the message.

Answer (score 1):

The use of super is to call the constructor of the super(base, parent) class which happens to be the `Exception` class